# How to remove a list from a list of lists based on list name

Tags: html, r, dataframe, list, html-table

I am trying to create a data frame that includes all the cases listed in this page:
https://nycourts.gov/reporter/slipidx/miscolo_2022_january.shtml

So the df will have four columns: title, court, date, Slip Op No

I have used the following code that gets me a list of lists:

```
theurl <- getURL("https://nycourts.gov/reporter/slipidx/miscolo_2022_january.shtml",.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
tables <- list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
```

I have tried to reduce the list of lists into one dataframe but it comes out very messy:

```
df <- reduce(tables, bind_rows)
```

Alternatively, I've been trying to clean up the NULL named lists, with the hope that then the reduce function will work better:
[image]

I've tried:

```
tables <- tables[-which(sapply(tables, function(x) x$name == "`NULL`"))]
```

but it doesn't work, leaving me with the same messy list of lists. I'd like to be able to replicate this code on other pages, so I don't want to lose the lists based on their number but only based on their name (NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to clean your list so that it does not contain elements named "NULL". Then you can use `rbindlist()` from `data.table` to merge everything while also adding an additional column indicating the source of each line.

```
tables[names(tables) != "NULL"] -> tb_new

data.table::rbindlist(tb_new, idcol = "file")
```